# Core Data CloudKit - List not updating after done onMove sorting

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I have a Core Data + CouldKit App where any changes made(sort order) via the onMove modifier will not show directly after tapping the done button. If I leave the view and come back the change is visible. I tried fetching the new updated items during the onMove function but this will create strange behaviours.

I have the following PersistenceController:

```
static let shared = PersistenceController()
    
let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    
var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return container.viewContext
}
    
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MonnyModel")
        
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
        
    container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
        
    context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
    try? context.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
}
...
```

My ViewModel:

```
@Published var lists: [Listing] = []
    
func fetchAllLists() {
    lists = PersistenceController.shared.fetchLists()
}
    
...
    
func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        
    // Make an array of items from fetched results
    var revisedLists: [Listing] = lists.map{$0}
        
    // Change the order of the items in the array
    revisedLists.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        
    // Update the sortOrder attribute in revisedLists to persist the new order. This is done in reverse order to minimize changes to the indices.
    for reverseIndex in stride(from: revisedLists.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
        revisedLists[reverseIndex].sortOrder = Int16(reverseIndex + 1)
    }

    // I've tried fetching it here which causes strange behaviour

    PersistenceController.shared.save()
}
```

I've tried fetching again in the move function but that didn't work. Doing this will keep the editMode on the list active but all the actions on each row disappear and the only thing I could do is to tap on the done button. I've also tried .objectWillChange.send() here but same strange behaviour is happening.

Here is the list in my View:

```
struct MyListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ListViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.lists.sorted(by: { $0.sortOrder < $1.sortOrder })) { list in
                ListCellView(viewModel: viewModel, list: list)
            }
            .onMove(perform: viewModel.move)
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                indexSet.forEach { index in
                    viewModel.deleteList(list: viewModel.lists[index])
                    viewModel.fetchAllLists()
                }
            })
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchAllLists()
        }
        .refreshable {
            viewModel.fetchAllLists()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for the suggestion. I will try and figure that out. I see they are fetching the data directly in a ViewModel but I am fetching the data in the PersistenceController. So not sure if the same solution will work.

Comment: Either way, in order to get updates, you need to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` and set a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to get updates, whether it be in a view model class, or the `PersistenceController` class. That is your only update mechanism besides `@FetchRequest` in the view.

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for the clarification! I've managed to add the `NSFetchedResultsController` and setting the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. Sorting works now but I keep having the glitchy bug when moving items in the list (before tapping the done button). On release of the moved list all the edit options (left minus icon and the right sort icon) on the items disappear, but the done button is still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix my issue by adding

`.environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)`

to my List in the view where the `Editbutton()` is located.

With this variable `@State var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive`